# VBA Loop Find Specific Date With User Input

Tags: vba, date, loops

I have range of dates with in B2 to the end of document. I am wanting to have the user be prompted with a input box" What date are you looking for", user will input the date. Then  user data will be used to to search row B2 to the end and find that specific date. If that date does not exist then another box will pop up letting the user know that they need to extend there range and try again. I keep getting "Add Days" even though when I input the correct data that is in that range it wont out put "Your Good". Can any one help me out?

```
 Sub Macro2()
     datein = CDate(InputBox("Date Project Will Start"))

     For Each c In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:D100").Cells
           If datein = c.Value Then MsgBox "Your Good"

     Next
     MsgBox "Add More Days"
 End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Presumably it's not, please write me some code to perform the above task.

Comment: sorry about that thought I copied over the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by grantnz indeed solves the issue of the value comparison, but you need to break the loop and perform some kind of validation to avoid the second message... Something like this:

```
Sub Macro2()
   Dim datein as Date, found as Boolean ' I prefer explicit variable declaration

   datein = CDate(InputBox("Date Project Will Start"))
   found = False

   For Each c In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:D100").Cells
       If datein = c.Value Then 
           MsgBox "Your Good"
           found = True
           Break ' You don't need to continue the iteration if you find a date
       End If
    Next
    If Not found Then 
        MsgBox "Add More Days" ' This message pops up only if found is false
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert datein to a date.

```
datein = CDate(InputBox("Date Project Will Start"))
```

Comment: That worked great but I am getting both message boxes. I updated the code above to the most current code that I have. I know that it is happening because its the next line of code to happen once out side of that loop. Do I put an if statement before the next or after the next?

Comment: You could just add  Exit Sub and End If after the "Your Good" message box.

Comment: @MarkAustin.  If you're going to include the fix in your question, it would be best to have it as a second block with a comment saying that it's the fix.  Otherwise, people coming across this question in the future will be puzzled as to what the original problem was.